# how to i change this insertion sort from ascending to descending - java

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

how can i change this insertion sort, from ascending to descending?  This is for java.

```
for(int top=1;top<dValues.length;top++){
    double item=dValues[top];//
    int i=top;
    while(i>0&&item<dValues[i-1]){
        dValues[i]=dValues[i-1];
        i--;
    }
    dValues[i]=item;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
while(i > 0 && item < dValues[i-1]) {
```

To this:

```
 while(i > 0 && item > dValues[i-1]) {
```

Right now, you're swapping when the value is *less* than. After the change, you're swapping when values are *greater* than, thus resulting in a descending list.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the comparisonn operator from `<` to `>`, so that the bigger (not the smaller) element is inserted first. It's as simple as that.

Comment: the one inside the inner while of course. The outer one doesn't contorl sorting, just the loop - that one has to stay.